# Discord.py How do I make my function loop?

Tags: discord, discord.py

How do I make the loop run every 5 seconds and update the queue list?

````
@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def queue_check():
    channel = client.get_channel(2342354325223424224)
    queue = []
    for members in channel.members:
        queue.append(members.display_name)
        queue_check.start()
        print(queue)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to start it, but not inside the loop itself

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def queue_check():
    channel = client.get_channel(2342354325223424224)
    queue = []
    for members in channel.members:
        queue.append(members.display_name)
        print(queue)


queue_check.start()
```

You can either start it in the `on_ready` event, in the global scope or in a command, you can also stop it using `queue_check.stop`

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I called the queue_check.start() it in the on_ready event and now it seems to be working. Is there a reason why it works in that function but not in the queue_check function? Just so i can understand why.

Comment: You're never starting the loop, so if you start the loop inside of it, it will never start

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a cog, start the loop in the `__init__` block, if it's on your main file, you can start it anywhere before `bot.run`

In any case the method is `queue_chech.start()`